# Inserting sequential numbers and line numbers for certain lines

Tags: regex, bash, awk, terminal, grep

I'm attempting to automate the following process:

1. Insert a number on line 1 (0001)
2. For the next 25 lines, insert sequential line numbers (1-25) along with two spaces
3. After line number 25, continue the next sequential number from line 1 (0002)
4. Do step 2 again
5. After this line number 25, continue sequentially (0003)
6. Do step 2 again
7. Etc.

The lines containing sequential numbers (0001, 0002, etc.) would contain just the number so I'm assuming adding a carriage return would be needed.

Is it also possible when numbering lines to include a space before numbers 1-9 so they line up with 10-25?

So something like...

```
0001
 1  This is text
 2  Some more text
 ↓
 9  Text here
10  Text here
 ↓
24  Additional text
25  And some more text
0002
 1  Text again
 2  More text
 ↓
 9  Text here
10  Text here
 ↓
24  Additional text
25  And some more text
0003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interesting question, I got this line, which gives required formatted output:

```
awk '{s=(NR-1)%25}!s{printf "%04d\n", ++k}{printf "%2d %s\n",s+1,$0}' file
```

Comment: Works perfectly. How would I add an extra space following a line number (1-25)? Also, any recommendations on learning more about `awk`? Thanks.

Comment: @jarhead `"%2d %s\n"` you can add spaces between `%2d` and `%s\n`

Answer (score 2):

using awk

```
awk 'FNR%25==1{printf "%04d\n",++i;s=1}{print s++,$0}' file
```

Comment: The second print should be a printf also: `awk 'FNR%25 == 1 {printf "%04d\n", ++i; s = 1}{printf "%2d  %s\n", s++, $0}'` so as to properly indent the 1-25 line numbers.